# I have a couple questions about Newton's mechanics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

i have a couple questions about Newton's mechanics :

1) can you tell me a example where the formula F = dP / dt is necessary?

2) what are the conditions to use conservation of energy? (i think there must be no external force and all internal forces must be conservative)

3) how can i prove that centripete force is directed towards the center ? i mean there is a proof but just for the value but not for the direction : why could it not be directed toward outside?

4) when must i choose the center (axe) for the force momentum and angular moment ?

5) why is always speed perpendicular to the position, and dv/dt perpendiular to the speed if the value of speed is constant?

Thank you !

Comment: Consider splitting this into multiple separate questions.

Comment: That is definitely not a **couple**. You should split the questions and elaborate upon each one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Finn covered 2, 3, and 5 fine. I think this should cover 1 and 4.

1. You need to use $F = dp/dt$ when the mass of the object is not constant. The most common cases of this are rockets, where the mass of the rocket changes as the propellant is expelled, and relativistic mechanics, where the relativistic mass increases at speeds near $c$. $F = ma$ is just the constant mass approximation, which comes directly from the product rule for derivatives: $dp/dt = v(dm/dt) +  m (dv/dt)$.
2. Before you start calculating angular momenta and torques. The better question is *where* to put it. Although your choice of center does not affect the final answer, judicious choice of a center can make the calculation much easier. As a quick heuristic, you want to put the center in a location that makes forces whose direction is unclear have zero torque. For example, in the classic example of a bar on a hinge, the normal force on the hinge does not have a constrained direction. Choosing the center of rotation at the hinge means you can do the torque balance without needing this information, simplifying the calculation. Again, you *can* do the torque balance about any point, but the resulting system of equations will be more complicated.

Comment: 1. can also be usefull when mass is constant.

Answer (score 1):

1: Rearange: $dP = F \cdot dt \rightarrow \int dP= \int Fdt \rightarrow P_2-P_1=F\delta t$

For example: your ball with mass m is travelling with 5 m/s, you apply a force of $1N$ over a time of $1s$. The new speed will be:

$m\cdot(v_2-v_1) = 1N \cdot 1s$
...

---

2: Conservation of energy happens when A) the incoming energies and outgoing energie in a system are equal and yes, the internal force need to be conservative

---

You can do the following:

Let's say a point mass rotates around a center m.
You introduce a coordinate system with $e_r$ being directed towards the mass and $e_\phi$ turned counter clockwise.
Now the position of the ball is:

$$x=r\cdot e_r$$
Now differentiate that and use: $\frac{d}{dt}e_r = d_\phi \dot{\phi}$
You will end up with:
$$\ddot{x} = e_r\cdot(\ddot{r}-r\cdot\dot{\phi}^2) + e_\phi\cdot(2\dot{r}\dot{\phi} +r\ddot{\phi})$$

You see that the acceleration is in the opposite direction of $e_r$ which is directed from the center to the mass.

---

4: I don't quiet understand that question but you will need to choose a center when you make an equation. angular momentum etc. is not something fixed but always relative to a point. So you will need to choose a center as a reference.

---

5: Check proof 3. This is only the case btw. if you have a circular motion. 
You can basically think about it this way:

1. Draw an arrow.
2. Draw another arrow that starts at the tip of the other and is rotated slightly.
3. If you keep doing this, you would end up with a circle.

Now take the first 2 arrows and let them start at the same point. You will see that the difference of those 2 points is perpendicular to both of them (approximately).

[image]